# Django---->app_label in models

Tags: django-models

I have defined `app_label` and migrating through database routers concept, but table name is creating `appname_model` name. So, how to change tablename in database if `app_label` is defined in a model through migrate command?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `db_table = "your_table_name"` in the `Meta` class of your model. See [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#db-table) of the doc.